# How to hide Chapter N in a documentclass{report} and number the chapter titles?

Tags: chapters, titles, report, section-titles

I've already hidden the `Chapter N` above every chapter title successfully by using the package `titlesec` and the following code in my `main.tex` file:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
```

Now I want to put only the chapter numbers in front of every chapter title like in the table of contents and the sections of each chapter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hang` option in place of `display`. This way, the chapter number will be on the same line as the title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Quantum materials and low temperature physics}
\section{Question 1}
\end{document}
```